# How to retrieve specific value of an array from firestore

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving specific data as an array from firestore, the value is the there on the console.log(), but i cant seems to retrieve the specific data from the array itself,

here's my event.ts

```
import { Event } from '../../models/event';

 invitedEvents: Event[] = [];

 this.invitedEvents = invitedEvents;
      console.log(invitedEvents, invitedEvents.name);
```

on console.log()

[image: Screenshot of the console log]

as you can see the `invitedEvents.name` return value of undefined, i'm sure you guys know the proper way of retrieving the value of name, send help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to `invitedEvents` is an array. So if you need to access you can't directly like `invitedEvents.name` like this, here is the few ways to access.

```
for(let item of invitedEvents){
   console.log("Data",item);
   console.log("Specific Name",item.name);
}
```

This example is used to print multiple values.

If you have only one value.Simply do like this.

```
 console.log("Specific Name Second way", invitedEvents[0].name);
```

I hope its helps you.

Thanks,

Muthu

Comment: thank you this really help! i have made a simplest mistake, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The object is in the array, so you have to access object from array first `invitedEvents[0]`

```
 console.log(invitedEvents, invitedEvents[0].name);
```

Comment: thank you, i really need to so much research on coding!